# what is the name of this lightbulb

Tags: light, light-bulb

There is an engraving on the bulb: 6v? 120v

This is for a motion-activated floodlight and I want to replace it with an LED but I don't know what to look for that fits this socket.

[image: ?]

Comment: "Bob". But seriously, measure the spacing & length of the pins and hopefully it will match up with one of the standard sizes (G4, etc.).

Comment: That's "GY", not 6V. GY describes the base/pins, but there are different sizes. It's most likely a GY6.35 - measure the distance between the pins (6.35mm is 1/4"). I don't see any indication of the wattage though - is there anything on the other side?

Comment: Good point on GY @brhans

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  - I was going to say "Dimwit" This is what i call my drunk uncle Bob.

Comment: @AlaskaMan Aha, because he is a...dim bulb!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps Halogen 100W.

[image]

Not sure what the 6V is. Maybe "GV", Walmart's Great Value. They have these bulbs.

Or GY, for GY-type pin-lamp base. There are different pin spreads under the GY family, so make sure you have the right one. See also  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-pin_lamp_base (as suggested in the comments by brhans)

Here's an overview for any interested readers:

[image]

From https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/b7/73/19/c0beebbacf9410/US8888332.pdf

Here's a link to the above bulb:

[https://www.wayfair.ca/HeathZenith--100W-Halogen-Replacement-Bulbs-SL5591A2A-L338-K~HEH1120.html?refid=GX185650380210-HEH1120&device=c&ptid=266190925378&targetid=pla-266190925378&network=g&ireid=3346990&gclid=CjwKCAjwxuuCBhATEiwAIIIz0aQYFiIG9NljPwFZQVfdkUB0BdFae-QcAWGvnQl_A0sqbbXqZTJJHxoCRPUQAvD_BwE](https://www.wayfair.ca/HeathZenith--100W-Halogen-Replacement-Bulbs-SL5591A2A-L338-K%7EHEH1120.html?refid=GX185650380210-HEH1120&device=c&ptid=266190925378&targetid=pla-266190925378&network=g&ireid=3346990&gclid=CjwKCAjwxuuCBhATEiwAIIIz0aQYFiIG9NljPwFZQVfdkUB0BdFae-QcAWGvnQl_A0sqbbXqZTJJHxoCRPUQAvD_BwE)